# Swift 3 - Programmatically build a button with an image and label

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, uistackview

I am currently trying to build an interface (programmatically) with 5 x buttons, containing an image and a label.

I have done this successfully for ONE button using a UIStackView (holding the UIButton and a UIlabel).

I have two questions for this forum…

1. A UIButton can be built to display a title OR an image, can it have both?
2. Can a ‘for in’ loop be used to generate 5 x individual buttons?  i.e: a way to re-use code instead of typing out code for 5 x buttons, 5 x labels, 5 x stack views.

My working UIStackView button code is as follows:

```
    // Button
    let btnSettings = UIButton()
//  btnSettings.setTitle("Settings", for: .normal)
    btnSettings.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "star-in-circle"), for: .normal)
    btnSettings.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
    btnSettings.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
    btnSettings.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    btnSettings.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSettings), for: .touchUpInside)
    btnSettings.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Text Label
    let textLabel = UILabel()
    textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    textLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
    textLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
    textLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    textLabel.text = "Settings"
    textLabel.textAlignment = .center

    // Stack View
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
    stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
    stackView.spacing = 1.0

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(btnSettings)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.view.addSubview(stackView)

    // Constraints
    stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

**Update / Solved Question 1**

I needed to use the button.setBackgroundImage() in order for the button title to show up with the image.

```
btnSettings.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "star-in-circle"), for: .normal)
btnSettings.setTitle("Button Title", for: .normal)
btnSettings.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: first question answer is both a UIButton can have both Title and Label and Second Answer yes you can make buttons with the help of Loop but for the action you have to give tag to each UIButton.

Comment: @GurinderBatth Thanks for your answer.  Any helpful advice on how?  I have tried adding both the button.setTitle() and button.setImage() to my code, but it only displays the image, not both image AND title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Of course, UIButton can have both an image or/and text. You can use:

   ```
   button.setImage(image: UIImage?, for: UIControlState)
   button.setTitle(title: String?, for: UIControlState)
   ```
2. Create a function that will return UIButton and do something like that:

   ```
   let button = generateButton()
   stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
   ```

Comment: Thanks Michal, adding the two lines you mention in answer to my question #1, ignores the title.  ie: it only shows the image.  I changed the background colour of the button background in case the title was hiding.  It there an order of background vs foreground for the image?  Does the image sit in front of the text or text in front of image?  Where would I expect to see the button title in relation to the button image?

Comment: Title should show on the right side of image and it should be above background.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  The fact that I have both my button and my text label in a StackView may be hindering the display of the button title.  I will go and do more testing with just the basic elements outside of the stack.  I will try your second answer to my for-in loop once I fix my button.  Thanks Michal

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept my answer if this was helpful ;) Good luck.